# SSL Certificate not from Hosting provider

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm new to all the ssl stuff.

Is it possible to have an SSL Certificate from different SSL Certificate provider than my hosting company or the hosting and SSL Certificate must come from the same company?

For example, if I host a site in Godaddy, do I must get the SSL Certificate from then (Goddady) as well? or I can do it through some other cheaper SSL Certificate provider?

If it's possible to have SSL Certificate not from the Hosting provider, I would be happy to have a reference by links or something...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is off-topic cause it's not related to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have an SSL Certificate from different SSL Certificate provider than my hosting company

Yes.

---

> Or the hosting and SSL Certificate must come from the same company?

No.

---

> If it's possible to have SSL Certificate not from the Hosting provider

In many instances, you can get a free Class 1 server certificate [Startcom](http://www.startcom.org/) or [CAcert](http://www.cacert.org/). The certificates are trusted by most desktop and mobile browsers. Class 1's are domain validated via email and *don't* allow wildcards. If you need a wildcard, then you'll have to purchase a Class 2 or higher. Startcom and CAcert charge for revocation, if needed.